# Can linux be windows substitute?

Tags: windows, migration

can i use linux as a substitute of windows? i mean Can i use MS Office, Photoshop and other softwares which i usually use in windows?

Comment: Your main question is argumentative and subjective, if you want narrow the scope and ask if you can use windows apps on Linux then please update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

You're asking this in a place where almost all of us use Ubuntu instead of Windows as our main operating system. The obvious answer is: yes.

You cannot simply install Microsoft Office and Photoshop as their programming is for Windows (or Mac). However you can install a "virtual" install of Windows under something called VirtualBox. This is like running a small computer inside of Ubuntu and it'll give you access to everything you need from Windows. Because you're running two operating systems at once you need a slightly beefier computer to get away with this.

There is also a compatibility layer called Wine that allows you to install Windows software. This often gives better performance applications with a lower resource overhead but this is traded against software support; not everything will run and what does might be buggy. You can check specific applications on http://appdb.winehq.org

Then there's alternative software. OpenOffice and GIMP are often touted as the open-source alternatives for MS Office and Photoshop. In my opinion OpenOffice will get the job done for *most* things. GIMP is also fine but if you're using advanced features in Photoshop, you'll probably miss a lot.

You should also consider perhaps moving certain tasks onto the web. For most of my word processing and spreadsheets, I now use Google Docs. It's completely cross platform and has some nice collaborative features. It's not as powerful as OpenOffice or MS Office but I don't need it to be.

I personally need Photoshop for my work (I'm a web developer when I'm not answering questions here) and I use VirtualBox to run a Windows XP install when I need it.

Comment: Just an additional note...some versions of Photoshop/Adobe suite rewrite the MBR and kill grub if you dual boot.  Thought it was worth noting.

Comment: Are you serious? Isn't it an offense to manipulate a foreign computer without reason?

Comment: @maaartinus What?

Comment: What what? When you hack a foreign computer, you can have a problem with law. When a OS rewrites the MBR, it may have a reason for it, so it may be OK, when Photoshop does it, there's no reason.

Comment: @maaartinus I didn't know who you were replying to and therefore no idea what context you were talking in. It's true that Photoshop has no good reason to do anything to your MBR but I'd be mortally shocked if there weren't something in the EULA where you give it permission to destroy your computer, sell all your personal files to criminals, and sell one of your kidneys on the black market.

Comment: That's quite possible, but such an EULA is probably invalid in many countries. However, I'm happy I don't need to use that piece of crap.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use other open source (and free) sofwares that substitute those, too... for instance:
MS Office -> OpenOffice or LibreOffice
Photoshop -> GIMP

Those programs, in general lines, do the same things as the ones you were using.
On the other hand, if you need a specific program that has no substitute for linux, you can always setup a Virtual Machine, install Windows on it, and install only the programs you need. That's what I do.

Answer (score -1):

Excuse me for this question, but... do you *own* a license for MSOffice, other for Windows and another one for Photoshop? If so (I do hope so!), you *should* stick to Windows (pretty clear, isn't it). Other else... well... let's view it from another point of view ;)

- MS Office --> OpenOffice / LibreOffice : not the same, but almost
- Photoshop --> GIMP: not the same, but pretty good indeed!
- Windows --> Ubuntu: no doubt! ;)

Any way, if you *do own* all those licenses, you could also use a VirtualMachine (both VMWare and VirtualBox have FREE versions) in your Ubuntu to install Windows and all that software.

Comment: Why are you questioning whether somebody owns a license for something?

Comment: I know 'that' hurts, but the *truth is* that we all know how this works. So, I reaffirm my questions.